# Modify array with user input?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm using this code to add user input into my arrays when clicking the "ADD" button.

```
int newcompartment;
string newproductcode, newname, newaddress;
float newweight;

newcompartment = int.Parse(txtcompartment.Text);
newproductcode = txtproduct.Text;
newname = txtname.Text;
newaddress = txtaddress.Text;
newweight = float.Parse(txtqty.Text);

if ((newcompartment > 0) && (newcompartment < productcode.Length) && (rbtnoccupied.Checked == true))
{
      if (productcode[newcompartment - 1] != "")
      {
           MessageBox.Show("Compartment is occupied !");
      }   
      else
      {
           MessageBox.Show("You have successfully added a new array data!");
           compartmentno[newcompartment - 1] = newcompartment;
           productcode[newcompartment - 1] = newproductcode;
           name[newcompartment - 1] = newname;
           weight[newcompartment - 1] = newweight;
           address[newcompartment - 1] = newaddress;   
      }
}
```

What I'm wondering is if it's possible to have a *"MODIFY"* button where user can enter new inputs to replace some or all of the previously added data in the array?

Just in case if it's needed , my GUI consist of 5 textbox and 2 radio buttons (`compartment no` , `product code` , `name` , `weight` , `address` ) & (`Occupied` /`Empty`).

Comment: Do yo want a button where you can input a text?

Comment: what is your question exactly? You want to get an index an modify your array data?

Comment: If you used List<string> instead of a string array, you could use its .Add method to add items into it.

Comment: I want to allow the user to input their data in the textboxes & radiobutton and when clicking the "Modify" button , the new data inputted will replace the old array data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't the same logic work if you remove the nested if else? So you can use it as ADD/MODIFY button. If it is a new compartment number it will get added. Otherwise if it is old, then it will get updated.  For removing the compartment, you can only accept the compartment number. If it exists, remove the entry from all the arrays.

```
if ((newcompartment > 0) && (newcompartment < productcode.Length) ) 

//removed this condition
//&& (rbtnoccupied.Checked == true))

{
      //Remove this if else condition. Always update the values.
      //if (productcode[newcompartment - 1] != "")
      //{...}
      //else
      //{...}

      MessageBox.Show("You have successfully added/modified an array data!");
      compartmentno[newcompartment - 1] = newcompartment;
      productcode[newcompartment - 1] = newproductcode;
      name[newcompartment - 1] = newname;
      weight[newcompartment - 1] = newweight;
      address[newcompartment - 1] = newaddress;   
}
```

**EDIT:**

A better approach would be to create a type called Compartment and use a collection which you can modify, instead of handling multiple arrays.

```
 public class Compartment
    {
        private int compartmentID;
        private string address;
        private string weight;
        private string name;

        public int CompartmentID
        {
            get { return compartmentID; }
            internal set { compartmentID = value; }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string Weight
        {
            get { return weight; }
            set { weight = value; }
        }           

        public string Address
        {
            get { return address; }
            set { address = value; }
        }
    }



 public class Form1
    {
        private List<Compartment> compartments;

        public void Form_Load()
        {
            compartments = new List<Compartment>();
        }

        private void AddCompartment(string name, string weight, string address)
        {
            Compartment newCompartment = new Compartment() { CompartmentID = compartments.Count + 1, Address = address, Name = name, Weight = weight };

            compartments.Add(newCompartment);
        }

        private void UpdateCompartment(int id, string name, string weight, string address)
        {
            //Update based on id
        }

        private void RemoveCompartment(int id)
        {
            compartments.Remove(id);
        }
    }
```